# use createVNode for antdvue component cannot resolve?

Tags: vuejs3, antdv

```
i use antd vue model to create a confirm modal,and use createVNode for my content
```

```
 const modalRef = Modal.confirm({
     content: createVNode(CategoryTreeAddModal),
     centered: true,
     icon: undefined,
     onCancel: (event) => {
       console.log(CategoryTreeAddModal)
       // modalRef.destroy();
     },
     onOk: (event) => {
       console.log(CategoryTreeAddModal)
       // modalRef.destroy();
     }
   })
```

and this is my content code

```
<template>
 <a-form ref="formRef" :model="formState" :rules="rules" class="login-form">
   <a-form-item ref="name" name="name">
     <a-input v-model:value="formState.name" placeholder="请输入名称" />
   </a-form-item>
 </a-form>
</template>
```

it just warning me Failed to resolve component:a-input  a-form-item  a-form, how to resolve,ijust wanna use this way to create my confirm modal

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 const instalce = getCurrentInstance()
 const vnode = createVNode(CategoryTreeAddModal)
 vnode.appContext = instance.appContext
 const modalRef = Modal.confirm({
     content: vnode,
     centered: true,
     icon: undefined,
     onCancel: (event) => {
       console.log(CategoryTreeAddModal)
       // modalRef.destroy();
     },
     onOk: (event) => {
       console.log(CategoryTreeAddModal)
       // modalRef.destroy();
     }
   })
```